# Can I add non-atomic values in a foreign key column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on a database for my school project to produce a functional database from example tables given in the project scenario.

In the example table there's a column named "Itineraries" which has multiple values within one cell such as 'London Tower Hill, Greenwich, Whitstable'. I felt the best way to reduce redundancy was to create a separate 'Destinations' table as shown below

```
create table Destinations(
    DestinationID varchar(5) primary key,
    Name varchar(45)
);
```

I use the DestinationID as a foreign key dependancy in the Itineraries table as scripted below.

```
create table Itineraries(
    ItineraryID varchar(5) primary key,
    Name varchar(20),
    DestinationID varchar(5) foreign key references Destinations(DestinationID)
);
```

Is there a way to insert multiple destinations in one row and still reduce redundancy?

Any advice is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 3):

To implement a many-to-many relationship in a normalised fashion a *"bridge table"* is usually employed, which does the job of linking the two sides of the relationship.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Destinations (
    DestinationID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name VARCHAR(45)
);

CREATE TABLE Itineraries (
    ItineraryID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE ItineraryDestinations (
    ItineraryID VARCHAR(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Itineraries(ItineraryID)
    ,DestinationID VARCHAR(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Destinations(DestinationID)
);
```

As you can see above, each row in the `ItineraryDestinations` table includes the ID of a record in both the `Itineraries` and `Destinations` table, allowing you to add multiple destinations to itineraries, and vice versa, by adding multiple rows, one for each itinerary > destination link.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are going through is called "normalisation" (or "normalization", depending on your style guide). You will probably find lots of guides online if you search for that.

In your case, you have a "many-to-many relationship": an itinerary has multiple destinations, but a destination occurs in multiple itineraries. Foreign keys can only represent one-to-many relationships, so in a normalised database schema we introduce a new entity (called a "join table", "pivot table", "bridge table", or similar names) to represent the relationship:

```
 CREATE TABLE Destinations_Itineraries
 (
      DestinationID varchar(5) foreign key references Destinations(DestinationID),
      ItineraryID varchar(5) foreign key references Itineraries(ItineraryID)
 )
```

Each row in this table represents *the association of a particular itinerary to a particular destination*. This breaks our many-to-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships.

We can then query (or join to) this table to find all the destinations on an itinerary, or all the itineraries which include a destination, rather than trying to store that information directly on the `Destinations` table or the `Itineraries` table.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I'll definitely apply this

Answer (score 0):

Well the only way to do that in one row is to add multiple destination columns in your Itineraries table, for example destination1 , destination2 and so on. But this would most likely produce a sparse Itineraries table.

So I would suggest you to use a n:m relation between the tables Destination and Itineraries. Then you can allocate multiple Destinations to multiple Itineraries.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement that advice